# Is PhotoBucket a viable solution to host a website's photo galleries

Tags: api, image-hosting, photobucket

I'm currently working with a lot of photographers and will probably be picking up development on a professional photography site soon.

With that in mind, and I can't stop thinking about a way I can implement a user-friendly photo gallery hosting solution where the site owner can upload images themselves without any webmaster intervention.

Kind of like a CMS for image hosting.

The idea is:
 - The user can log in to PhotoBucket
 - Upload their gallery
 - Visit an admin section of the site
 - Enter the new gallery name to the listing

And... Voila, the gallery automagically gets displayed on the website in a clean lightbox-style presentation format (ie, no iframe nonsense).

I took a brief look at the API and it looks promising.
Is this a viable solution?

Bonus points if you have implemented something like this with Photobucket and/or another 3rd-party image hosting site.

*Note: Purchasing a premium account is expected if necessary. The limitations on free accounts at most image hosting sites are just too restrictive to be useful.*

Answer (score 1):

Completely viable, yes.  A good idea... depends.

I did something similar with imgur.com a while ago kind of testing the same thing.  Technical issues I couldn't really find, like you said especially if you pay for a premium account.

I just felt out of control with my content privacy wise.  That said Photobucket does have a way of making your images private, however I couldn't find anything in the API docs saying that you could retrieve private images.

Assuming you could retrieve private images and privacy / control issues are covered then I think the last thing I can think of you'd want to evaluate is if you care whether or not that you are depending on their service to keep your images hosted.  Admittedly they are a large site and aren't likely to have any major outages.  But it's a possibility and you wouldn't have any control as to when they come back online.  Also what if Photobucket unexpectedly shut its doors one day, or got raided by the FBI or something nuts like that... all of it is out of your control.